# Separate init segments per representation in MP4Box

Tags: mpeg-dash, mp4box

I am trying to reproduce BBC's AVC3 experiments (http://rdmedia.bbc.co.uk/dash/ondemand/bbb/2/client_manifest-separate_init.mpd) and generate a DASH MPD using MP4Box that

1. has avc3 codec type (i.e. using inband switching mode)
2. segment template
3. separate initialization segment for each representation.

I am unable to achieve this using the following command line

```
MP4Box -dash 2000 -frag 2000 -rap -frag-rap -bs-switching inband ../bbb_clip_v_1700k.mp4:id=vid0 ../bbb_clip_v_2550k.mp4:id=vid1  ../bbb_clip_v_3850k.mp4:id=vid2  ../bbb_clip_v_5800k.mp4:id=vid3 -out test1.mpd -url-template
```

I tried various combinations of -segment-name, but I've been unsuccessful. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GPAC maintainer here. Just use `-bs-switching no`.

FYI I am the only maintainer trying to follow the activity here. We'd appreciate if you could use our official tracker instead: https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues - that would allow you to have faster answers!